# How to implement Google Analytic in Titanium for iPhone and Android?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-analytics, titanium

I want to implement google analytic service in my titanium app. I tried [MattTuttle/titanium-google-analytics module](https://github.com/MattTuttle/titanium-google-analytics/blob/master/mobile/ios/documentation/index.md) and used this code:

```
var GA = require('analytics.google');
var tracker = GA.getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-X");
tracker.trackEvent({
    category: "my event category",
    action: "clicked",
    label: "how many (c)licks?",
    value: 3
});
```

I replaced key by my new app key but when i use my app for multi-language, application crashes most time.

Please suggest me any how i can implement google analytic in my titanium application.

Comment: What error message do you get when application crashes?

Comment: checkout [this](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/153996/how-to-use-google-analytics-module-in-titanium-android-app) link. It will fix your Problem.

Comment: error was something like
<Warning>:Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
<Warning>: Application exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
<Warning>: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.

@daniula

Comment: @Dragon this link give only a examle to implement google analytic, i already follow these instruction while implementing.

Comment: "MPUSystemMediaControls" doesn't seem to be related to the Google Analytics module, is there any other error you see? What's the error message on Android? If you strip your app down and just include the Analytics functionality, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

may be this [link](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/78151/using-google-analytics-in-titanium-mobile) will help you to implement Google analytic in titanium.
or
try this one:  https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/153996/how-to-use-google-analytics-module-in-titanium-android-app

please let me know if it won't work.
Thanks